# ProgressBar - Adding glowing effect and rounded edges

Tags: android, android-progressbar

I am trying to add this glowing effect/drop shadow around progress bar. To make edges rounded, I came across this solution of using `LinearProgressIndicator` instead of `ProgressBar` and adding `app:trackCornerRadius` property. Now I need solution for this glowing effect.

[image]